# Delegate touch event to another view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-event

I have list view with. User can open dialog on full screen `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` that overlay this list view. When user touches the background of this dialog it closes.

I need to delegate this touch event to list view. I mean, after `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` on bg i need to close dialog (it works fine), and start `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` on list view.

I tried something like this:

```
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialog_bg)).setOnTouchListener(new    View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);                          
                        activity.findViewById(R.id.fr_projects_list).dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                        close();

                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

It starts `ACTION_DOWN` on list view. But thats all. ACTION_MOVE and others doesn't work =/

Answer (score 1):

You are dispatching only `ACTION_DOWN` that's why you are not getting any other actions.
Try dispatching all actions.

```
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.dialog_bg)).setOnTouchListener(new    View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    MotionEvent motionEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(event);                          
                    activity.findViewById(R.id.fr_projects_list).dispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                    if(event.getAtction==MotinEvent.ACTION_UP) close();
                    return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: After i make touch event i close dialog. So after that there will no others events on dialog. And i should with events of list view.

Comment: @Suvitruf I updated my answer. Just a try.. Call Close only when action is ACTION_UP

Comment: Customer wants to close dialog on ACTION_DOWN, not ACTION_UP. It's not my choice )=

Comment: Ok.. I guess if you close dialogue on ACTION_DOWN, theynother event should by default called on ListView. Try setting touchlistner to your listview. I am not 100% sure but you can try.

Comment: This is helpfull, but it doesn't work in 100% if target view has margin then cloned touch will be dislocated a bit. Any help with this problem?